# How to fetch all file content from XML using xpath?

Tags: php, xml, xpath

**I am working on PHP 5.6.3**

Below is the code in which $xml contains XML Content.

```
$xml  = '<TOPTag><Order><doc DocumentName="Doc1">TEST1</doc><doc DocumentName="Doc2">TEST2</doc></Order></TOPTag>';
$stk  = simplexml_load_string($xml);
foreach($stk->xpath('/TOPTag/Order/doc') as $doc)
{
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($doc);
    echo "</pre>";
}
```

I need all the data including doc content for all doc xpath.

Actually result of above code is below which does not have doc content for first object. It just return doc content for last object only.

```
SimpleXMLElement Object
(
    [@attributes] => Array
        (
            [DocumentName] => Doc1
        )
    [0] => TEST1  <- NOT COMING in OUTPUT - PHP VERSION 5.6.3
)
SimpleXMLElement Object
(
    [@attributes] => Array
        (
            [DocumentName] => Doc2
        )

    [0] => TEST2
)
```

We need to get all data (doc content) for all object.

Can you please advise?

Comment: echo $doc[0]; // TEST1 and TEST2

Comment: Have you checked that TEST1 printed by above example? Its not fetching and printing TEST1. Kindly check its not printing TEST1.

Comment: https://eval.in/432303

Comment: I am working on PHP 5.6.3 and output is NOT coming as per your above link. Your tool RUN code on PHP 5.5.14 :(

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure why your for-each isn't working, but have a look at the example from [the document page](http://php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.xpath.php):

```
while(list( , $node) = each($result)) {
    echo '/a/b/c: ',$node,"\n";
}
```

And apply that to your code:

```
$result = $stk->xpath('/TOPTag/Order/doc');
while(list( , $node) = each($result)) {
{
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($node);
    echo "</pre>";
}
```

Alternatively, this may also work (untested):

```
foreach($stk->xpath('/TOPTag/Order/doc') as $doc)
{
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($doc->asXML());
    echo "</pre>";
}
```